# How to search part of pattern in regex python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I can match pattern as it is. But can I search only part of the pattern? or I have to send it separately again.
e.g. `pattern = '/(\w+)/(.+?)'`
I can search this pattern using re.search and then use group to get individual groups.
But can I search only for say `(\w+)` ?
e.g.

```
pattern = '/(\w+)/(.+?)'
pattern_match = re.search(pattern, string)
print pattern_match.group(1)
```

Can I just search for part of pattern. e.g. pattern.group(1) or something

Comment: added is the example pattern. I am trying to match part of pattern without sending it separately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make any part of a regular expression optional by wrapping it in a non-matching group followed by a `?`, i.e. `(?:` ... `)?`.

```
pattern = '/(\w+)(?:/(.+))?'
```

This will match `/abc/def` as well as `/abc`.

In both examples `pattern_match.group(1)` will be `abc`, but `pattern_match.group(2)` will be `def` in the first one and an empty string in the second one.

For further reference, have a look at `(?:x)` in the special characters table at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

**EDIT**

Changed the second group to `(.+)`, since I assume you want to match more than one character. `.+` is called a "greedy" match, which will try to match as much as possible. `.+?` on the other hand is a "lazy" match that will only match the minimum number of characters necessary. In case of `/abc/def`, this will only match the `d` from `def`.

Answer (score 0):

That pattern is merely a character string; send the needed slice however you want.  For instance:

```
re.search(pattern[:6], string)
```

uses only the first 6 characters of your pattern.  If you need to detect the end of the first pattern -- and you have no intervening right-parens -- you can use

```
rparen_pos = pattern.index(')')
re.search(pattern[:rparen_pos+1], string)
```

Another possibility is

```
pat1 = '/(\w+)'
pat2 = '/(.+?)'
big_match = re.search(pat1+pat2, string)
small_match = re.search(pat1, string)
```

You can get more innovative with expression variables ($1, $2, etc.); see the links below for more help.
http://flockhart.virtualave.net/RBIF0100/regexp.html
https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html

Comment: thanks for the answer...the first is hard coded and for second one we are still passing 2 patterns. I guess I have to send 2 patterns.